# W3 Bootstrap Template Missing Columns?

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4

I am create a movie web app and currently the bootstrap template [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_store&stacked=h). For some reason on my website there are columns that are missing as shown in the picture below. I have no idea why these columns are missing as I can't find anything in the HTML of the page that would be causing it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my html code.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">    
  <h3>Movies</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    {% for item in data %}
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="shows/{{ item.show_id }}"><img src="{{ item.poster }}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a>
        <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

---

**Image of missing columns**

[image]

Comment: due to image size probably

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, It's due to images sizes are different.

Comment: Do you know of anyway of fixing so that images don't "overreach" a certain "boundary" and cause these missing boxes?